# JOOQ Metamodel: why is there no Table.rename(String)?

Tags: java, code-generation, jooq

I am dynamically creating and using physical DB tables for which I only have one metamodel object. An example: I have one JOOQ class `Customer` in my metamodel, but I have `CUSTOMER1`, `CUSTOMER2`, etc. at runtime. I'd like to write strongly typed JOOQ queries for these dynamic tables. The following seems to do the trick:

```
Customer CUSTOMER1 = Customer.rename("CUSTOMER1")
```

Of course, there's a whole bunch of tables for which I need to do this. Unfortunately, I cannot leverage the `rename` method generically, because it is not part of the `Table<R>` interface. Is this an oversight or a deliberate measure against something I am missing?

Is there a robust and elegant way to achieve what I want, i.e. without resorting to reflection?

*EDIT*: the two tables are never used jointly in the same query. Concrete usage pattern is the following: At any given moment, a DB synonym `CUSTOMER` will point to one (the active), while the other is being modified (the shadow copy). Once the modification is complete, roles are swapped by pointing the synonym at the other one, and we start over. We do this to minimize "downtime" of heavy reporting result tables.

Comment: Will you have `CUSTOMER1` and `CUSTOMER2` in a single query, or are those mutually exclusive tenants that appear only once per query?

Comment: @Lukas Eder: thanks, I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The answer to your question

The question being in the title:

> why is there no Table.rename(String)?

The feature was implemented in jOOQ 3.3 ([#2921](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2921)). The issue reads:

> As table renaming is not really a SQL DSL feature, the rename() method should be generated onto generated tables only, instead of being declared in org.jooq.Table

In fact, this argument doesn't really make much sense. There are other "non-DSL" utilities on the DSL types. I don't see why `rename()` is special. The method should be declared on `Table` as you suggested. This might be done in the future ([#13937](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13937)).

#### The answer to your problem

From the update of your question, I understand that you don't really need that fine-grained renaming control. jOOQ's out of the box multi-tenancy feature will do. This is called "table mapping" in the manual:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/runtime-schema-mapping

For the scope of a `Configuration` (most fine-grained scope: per-query level), you can rewrite any matching table name as such:

```
Settings settings = new Settings()
    .withRenderMapping(new RenderMapping()
    .withSchemata(
        new MappedSchema().withInput("MY_SCHEMA")
                          .withOutput("MY_SCHEMA")
                          .withTables(
         new MappedTable().withInput("CUSTOMER")
                          .withOutput("CUSTOMER1"))));
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas. Knowing that `Table.rename()` will come in 3.9, I will go with the reflection hack for now, since it is easier to migrate later on.

Comment: I really like the "the answer to your question" and "the answer to your problem" approach taken here. :) Sometimes, you simply don't know what you are doing well enough to be able to ask the right question...

Comment: @PerLundberg: It has a name: https://xyproblem.info. It's still a useful question, though. People will find the `rename()` method and think "this is for me". But then, it doesn't do exactly what they want, so they google `rename()` to see what options they have. It's one way of discovering the feature whose name they didn't know, "schema mapping."

Comment: Yeah, good points. As for myself, I stumbled upon the `rename()` method by coincidence when I was in fact looking for table-aliasing using `as()`....:-D

Comment: @PerLundberg: And then, you came here, in awe of what's possible :) (or, wondering, what you were originally looking for before all of this distraction)

Comment: @LukasEder Something like that yes. :)